# How to implement the image redirect with parameters?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, graphicimage

This is the way how a `commandButton` realizes the redirect with parameters.

```
<h:commandButton value="Check" action="#{GetInfoBean.getInfo}">
<f:param name="ID" value="4"></f:param>
</h:commandButton>
```

When this `commandButton` get clicked, it will pass the parameter named `ID` with value `4`. The managed bean `GetInfoBean`'s method `getInfo()` will return the new url.

But now, my question is how can I implement this redirect process using `image` or `graphicImage` since it doesn't have the `action` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the image using a `<h:commandLink>`:

```
<h:commandLink value="Check" action="#{GetInfoBean.getInfo}">
    <f:param name="ID" value="4"></f:param>
    <h:graphicImage value="/your/image.png" />
</h:commandLink>
```